# Adding multiple users to manage the same account in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I want the following functionality in Drupal 7: 
I have existing users which are created with profile2 and related to a special role(School Role). In this way a user has the right to manage their school page, manage the account etc. Now what if this user want to add another account to manage the same account.

Normal users(students Role) and school users have different registration forms.

How can I add another user to manage the same account but with different role. Like adding a parent-child relation, in which a account will be the primary one and the others like sub-accounts.

I cant add modules like Shared email or Multiple E-mail, because I want for different email or users to manage the same account.

Is there a way to do this in drupal 7? I searched for this type of scenario but didn't find anything to start with.

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/88622/15055

Comment: @leymannx that was helpful. Still trying to figure it out the connection between roles to make a redirect to the same account